# Livestream: Efficiency JPEG vs. MJPEG

Tags: xcode, swift, performance, live-streaming, mjpeg

I have a webserver displaying a livecam. 
It has two modes:

1. JPEG (displays current image on page refresh)
2. MJPEG (displays MJPEG stream)

At the moment i am using the JPEG mode. I download and display the Image 20x per second. 
This works perfectly without any delay. 
But it has a pretty high CPU usage (about 70% out of 200% on my iPhone 6S).

Code:

```swift
if let url = NSURL(string: "http://1.1.1.181:8085/?action=snapshot") {
    let request = NSURLRequest(URL: url, cachePolicy: .ReloadIgnoringLocalAndRemoteCacheData , timeoutInterval: 1)
    NSURLConnection.sendAsynchronousRequest(request, queue: NSOperationQueue.mainQueue()) {
        (response: NSURLResponse?, data: NSData?, error: NSError?) -> Void in
        if data != nil {
            self.imageView.image = UIImage(data: data!)                    
        } 
    }
}
```

My questions:

- Is there a more efficient way to download and display an image from
  an webpage?
- Is it more efficient to use the MJPEG stream. (If yes:
  which framework can you recommend)?

Comment: define efficient. What specifically are you tying to optimize for?

Comment: I assume you mean on the client. Then you don't want to do either. Encode on the server side to an h264 video. The phone has dedicated hardware for playback.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to decode and display h264 Videos?

Comment: No. There are plenty of resources on line for that.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you do need to use a video codec of some sort, since you have a video.  Trying to send individual frames like this is a waste of bandwidth and CPU.  I'm impressed that you're getting 20 FPS out of your current setup.

<s>MJPEG is a video codec that works by continually enhancing the image, in the exact same way that JPEG works.  Contents of frames that change are pushed as enhancements to what's already there, saving a lot of bandwidth.  MJPEG is also easy to implement, since if you can decode JPEG progressive, you can already decode MJPEG (maybe with some minor enhancements).</s> *May not be accurate, see comments below.*

In any case, there are far better video codecs available these days.  Many of them have hardware codecs, meaning work is offloaded to that codec chip rather than being handled by the CPU directly.  This is how high performance video is ran on hardware that would otherwise not be able to keep up.  Figure out what codec you want to use based on the system support that already exists for it on your target platform.  H.264 and VP8 are quite popular, with VP9 coming up.

Comment: H.264 would be an option.

Comment: Sorry, this is wrong : a MJPEG stream is actually a flow of plain JPEG images enclosed by two bytes : FFD8 at start and FFD9 at the end. There is no keyframes, nor picture enhancements in between. You likely confuse it with MPEG.

Comment: @Larry Thanks for the feedback.  I understand that there are no keyframes.  Isn't MJPEG typically done in the exact same method as progressively enhanced JPEG?  Are you saying that every frame in MJPEG stands alone, guaranteed, always?  Or is this just how some encoders implement?  I could have sworn I remember reading that it's done the same as progressive JPEG images...

Comment: From what I know about MJPEG, the images are standalones JPEG images one behind the other. That's the case with IP cameras. It is possible that JPEG images in the stream are encoded in progressive, but I have not yet had the opportunity to see a decoder really take advantage of the "progressivity" of the JPEG images in the stream to speed up the rendering.There is also the interlaced MJPEG format, but I admit that I have never tried to find out more about it.

Comment: By the way, as I see you're doing node.js, I found a project that you should like: it captures JPEG images from a MJPEG stream: https://github.com/nn1900/mjpeg-decoder

Answer (score 0):

There is hardly a difference between the two. The only difference is that with `M-JPEG`, the stream sends a sequence of `JPEG`s, instead of one per request, so you don't waste bandwidth opening a new connection per frame, which in cases can be negligible compared to the image size, and M-JPEG can cause image delays in low-bandwidth connections because of buffering instead of dropping frames.

[Motion JPEG — Encoding — Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motion_JPEG#Encoding)

[video surveillance on C# — CodeProject](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/15537/Camera-Vision-video-surveillance-on-C)